# Row click event on Kendo-angular2-grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Below is the grid that I have developed using Kendo-Angular2.
I need a click event on the row and in the event I need the row information.
I wrote a general click event and tried o get the row information, but it doesn't work if I go to second page in the pagination. Is there a simple row click event that gives the row information.

plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/h0fVaP4NykRiILA7dyHn?p=preview

click event code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.renderer.listen(this.gridRef.nativeElement, "mousedown", (event) => {
    if (!event.target.matches('tbody>tr *')) {
      return;
    }

    const gridData = this.grid.data;
    const tr = event.target.closest('tr');
    const dataItem = gridData.data[tr.rowIndex + this.grid.skip];

    console.log(dataItem);
  });
}
```

Comment: why not write it in the html?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I didn't get you. Can you please elaborate little..

Comment: this should be what you want: `http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/selection/`

Comment: I already saw that. It just gives me the rowindex. But I cant use that rowindex because when we do a sort, the index of the item changes and it gives the new index. I cant use this new index from the gridData to get the row information, because it will have the original index value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Angular Template

```
   <kendo-grid #gridUser
                  [kendoGridBinding]="gridData"
                  [pageSize]="10"
                  [pageable]="true"
                  [sortable]="true"
                  [selectable]="true"
                  (selectionChange)="gridUserSelectionChange(gridUser, $event)">
        <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="ID">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="nameThai" title="Name">
        </kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-pdf fileName="User.pdf"></kendo-grid-pdf>
        <kendo-grid-excel fileName="User.xlsx"></kendo-grid-excel>
      </kendo-grid>
```

Angular Component

```
 gridUserSelectionChange(gridUser, selection) {
     // let selectedData = gridUser.data.data[selection.index];
     const selectedData = selection.selectedRows[0].dataItem;
     console.log(selectedData);
 }
```